# how do i enable/view logs for nuget server on teamcity 8.1.4?

Tags: teamcity, nuget

i've setup a build step to build a nuget package and publish it as an artifact, and it's working fine, i can see it in the artifacts tab of the build. But the package is not published to the feed, the feed it's empty both for logged user and for guest user.

I suspect that the nuget server is not indexing the packages.

so, how do i enable/view logs for nuget server on teamcity 8.1.4 to further inspect the issue?

Answer (score 0):

My packages disappeared from my TeamCity's public feed today. I found out that it's because I removed the guest user from its only group. This group has permission to projects that produce the packages. After I added the guest back to this group, the packages reappear in the feed.

I have not tried the authenticated feed so I cannot comment on it.